# Using binary data inside doFinal() - javax.crypto.Cipher

Tags: java, binary, rsa, encryption

In my project, I xor'ed (sorry but dont know the proper verb) a string and encrypted with RSA-1024. Now I have an **xored and encrypted** string like:

> 994624f87a00f4c3066c2a2d38917fe4971be8ad4e6ba58d14cc8b27ab8db84ec2a577f7bda1839cb9843ce6f738f51807ba127b775725ef14e3cea61091bf1fdcfa1372e1975f1b9418b0ad396bea5e7d2a832b8c4161e3b0595f7ed7e57eeda0ad8ab7a7268c871ab4e6d13e3caccaa8b54740ec2d1b8d23d835ff77c78161

When i try to decrypt with...

```
Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, priKey);
byte[] cipherData = cipher2.doFinal(data);
```

it returns non-logical characters like

> â—?â—?â—?â—?â—?â—?â—?â—?

i know the reason; when bits that have proper ascii counterparts xored, the answer may not have an ascii counterpart. So im trying to find a different format such as binary to use inside doFinal().

Looking forward to an answer,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you XORing the plaintext? If you're going to encrypt it anyway, XORing doesn't seem to accomplish anything.

Beyond that `cipherData` is a misleading name: that's actually your (XORd) cleartext, since you are getting it from the decryption step.

If you continue with the XOR scheme, you need to XOR those bytes again before attempting to decode them into a String. When you do that step, you probably need to specify the encoding used, e.g., UTF-8, just to be safe.

Comment: Because its a term project and xoring is a requirement. Im not happy with that, though :) I know that I have to xor the decrypted text to reach the original message. The problem is that; i cant get decrypted text properly because cipher.dofinal(data) doesnt return the right output...

Comment: @Ismail Kuyu Try skipping the `XOR` step and verifying that the encryption/decryption is working properly. Since it's just `byte` data, it shouldn't matter, but it never hurts to chop out any complexity you can while debugging, then add it back later if you need it.

Comment: @Ismail Kuyu Also, are you sure that `data` is your ciphertext? The name makes it sound like it may be the original plaintext. Can you slap together the smallest example that will recreate your problem and put it in your question?

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for your help. although i said that its a requirement, i go around it and use mode function instead of xor :) btw, en/decryption works properly since i did them before xor stuff. Again, thanks for help...